# mvn release:prepare not committing changes

Tags: java, git, maven, gitlab, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to release my project using maven release:prepare command. My code resides in gitlab and I have provided my project url in the pom.xml but while trying to update in Git it fails. Could someone help me with in understanding what I could be doing wrong.
Build plugin is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <tagNameFormat>r@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
        <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

SCM tags are mentioned as below:

```
<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://gitlab-mac-p7.systems.private/test/testservice.git</developerConnection>
    <tag>testservice-0.100.0-delete</tag>
</scm>
```

Below is the error stack trace:

```
maven release:prepare The git-commit command failed Repository has been updated, but unable to write

[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git commit --verbose -F C:\Users\P7846763\AppData\Local\Temp\2\maven-scm-392995137.commit pom.xml"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\DEP\Code\eecc\testservice-feature-FMW-5241-releaseTest
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 03:03 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-19T15:08:55+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project testservice: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-commit command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] fatal: Repository has been updated, but unable to write
[ERROR] new_index file. Check that disk is not full and quota is
[ERROR] not exceeded, and then "git reset HEAD" to recover.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project testservice: Unable to commit files
Provider message:
The git-commit command failed.
Command output:
fatal: Repository has been updated, but unable to write
new_index file. Check that disk is not full and quota is
not exceeded, and then "git reset HEAD" to recover.
```

Comment: So have you checked for the things mentioned in the error message?

Comment: @JFabianMeier Yes I do have many other projects available in the Git and I am able to release those. Only difference being all other projects are released via Jenkins and this one is done with the help of this command - mvn release:clean release:prepare release:perform -Darguments="-DskipTests -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true" -e

Comment: How is the project being checked out by Jenkins? I suppose you are using the default setup to clone the project? Can you describe how you are doing that?